# Averages of a calculated field

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to calculate the average for each column or in this case box and wisker.  I.e. I want to get the average for the box highlighted in baby blue as shown in the attached image.

Each column was formed by a calculated field as shown in the image below.  From what I understand, to accomplish what I am after, I would apply a window_avg on this box and wisker plot or am I going down the wrong path?

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? How exactly do you want the average to be calculated? Please provide the sample input data and desired o/p in tabular format so that we can guide you in right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @Prem Thank you for the suggestions, does my edit fit the expectation?  Or am I still off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this -

- Create a calculated field `Avg_BorrowerAPR` as
  `{FIXED[Principal Groups]: AVG([Borrower APR])}`. Drag `Principal Groups` onto the
  Column shelf and drag above calculated field onto the Row shelf.
  Change Marks to Line graph (or something as per your preference).
- Again drag `Borrower APR` onto Rows shelf and draw the graph you have
  already built.
- This will create two graphs. Right click on Y-axis of below graph and
  select 'Dual Axis` and then again right click to select
  'synchronize'.
- Perform other necessary cosmetic changes and you are done!

Hope this helps! If this is not what you expected then let me know and we can solve it together.

Comment: @OmegaSupreme if you liked the solution then you should accept it as the right answer. It'll surely help others in case they encounter similar problem in future. Thanks!